# How to autosubmit form with ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

i m trying to submit my form without any user interaction,i don't know how to do that, do you have a lead for?

Thanks by advance

Below my code

Html form

```
<form id="myform" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="print_names" id="print_names" value="print_names" />
        <input type="submit" name="loginBtn" id="loginBtn" value="test" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Ajax part for submit

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myform').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'form.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response)
            {
```

Comment: you need to have an event to trigger submission. It can be anything but to sumarize it should be one action performed by the user or a timer

Comment: As a hint, if you don't want to trigger the ajax call on submit, you shouldn't attach it a `.submit()` handler :)

Comment: If I interpret `without any user interaction` as `after 15 seconds`, then you can do `setTimeout( launchMyAjaxCall, 15000 )`, of course `launchMyAjaxCall` being the function containing your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Your form has no target action, in that caase you could use just:

```
document.forms.myform.submit();
```

Comment: But that's just the vanilla version of OP's jQuery `$('#myform').submit()`...